# add eventViewController not showing anything

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, eventkit

I'm currently working on a agenda part of an app. I managed to show all my events and also go to the details from it and edit it. But when I want to add an event it shows me an empty view. I should mention that I have a custom datasource for my calendar.

To edit an Event I just do this in my ViewController.

```
  EKEventViewController *vc = [[EKEventViewController alloc] init];
        vc.event = [dataSource eventAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        vc.allowsEditing = YES;
       [calendar.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This is showing me the correct VC with the correct event.
Now this is my code for adding a event.

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]init];

    // set the addController's event store to the current event store.
    addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
    addController.editing = YES;
    // present EventsAddViewController as a modal view controller
    [self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

    addController.editViewDelegate = dataSource;
```

But when I run it I get an empty viewController. Can anybody help me with this?

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you sure that self.eventStore is not nil?

Comment: Maybe you should set the delegate ***before*** presenting the view. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you didn't create the event store. I looked at Apple's demo program, and I could eliminate all but 4 lines, and still get that edit controller to show up:

```
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)doStuff:(id)sender {
    EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]init];
    addController.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init]; 
    [self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: You are right! After initializing the eventstore it worked. But when I add an event, that event is added two times. Any help on that ?